# How well is a binomial distribution with $N=100,000$ approximated by a normal distribution?

Tags: normal-distribution, binomial-distribution, large-deviation-theory

When we consider a binomial distribution with large $N$ and $p=0.5$, this is approximately equal to a normal distribution with mean $\frac12N$ and standard deviation $\frac12\sqrt{N}$. However, according to [large deviations theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Large_deviations_theory), this does only hold when you are `close to the mean'. So the chance that you get value $0.8N$ may be different than the normal distribution would give you, for example.

I would like to know up to how many standard deviations the normal distribution is a good approximation for $N=100,000$. What is the largest integer $l$ such that for all $x$ which are at most $l$ standard deviations away from $\frac12$, the relative difference between the normal distribution pdf value and the binomial distribution pdf value is at most $10\%$?

Comment: If $Npq$ is large (thumb rule : greater than $9$), then the normal approximation is "good", no matter where we approximate the binomial distribution. With your parameters, the normal approximation will be excellent (see also the Central limit theorem)

Comment: @Peter, What is $N_{pq}$?

Comment: Good point, I confused pdf with cdf

Comment: For cdf, you can calculate the relative difference using theorem 2 in https://users.cecs.anu.edu.au/~bdm/papers/littlewood2.pdf

Comment: @Riemann Not $N_{pq}$ , $Npq$ meaning $N\cdot p\cdot q$ , where $N$ is the number of trials, $p$ is the probability of success and $q=1-p$ is the probability of a failure.

Comment: @Peter, thanks for the rule of thumb!

Comment: @The Phoenix, for the cdf of the binomial distribution it is impossible to calculate it directly, since you have so many terms to sum.

Answer (score 1):

With $\sigma^2 = N/4$, and for $x$ fixed, Stirling's formula gives an asymptotic expansion
$$ \frac{ 
\displaystyle{  \frac{1}{2^N} \binom{N}{N/2 + x \sigma} }
}
{
\displaystyle{
\frac{e^{-x^2/2}}{\sigma \sqrt{2 \pi}}
}
}
= 1 -  \frac{(x^4 - 6 x^2 + 3)}{12N} + \ldots $$
As $N \rightarrow \infty$ this recovers the central limit theorem.
Although this is for fixed $x$, this suggests that there is non-trivial error in the regime where $x^4 \sim N$.
Thus write $x = N^{1/4} y$ and repeat the analysis with Stirling's formula to obtain
$$ \lim_{N \rightarrow \infty} \frac{ 
\displaystyle{  \frac{1}{2^N} \binom{N}{N/2 + y N^{1/4} \sigma} }
}
{
\displaystyle{
\frac{e^{-x^2/2}}{\sigma \sqrt{2 \pi}}
}
}
=  e^{-y^4/12}.$$
In particular, for an error of 10 percent, one wants to take
$$y = \sqrt[4]{12 \log(1 + 1/9)},$$
or
$$k = \sigma x = N^{1/4} \sigma y = \frac{N^{3/4}}{2} \cdot \sqrt[4]{12 \log(1 + 1/9)} = N^{3/4} \cdot 0.530193 \ldots.$$
This is the answer as $N \rightarrow \infty$.  If you specialize to $N = 100000$, you get
$$k = 2981.499 \ldots $$
or
$$x = 18.85666\ldots $$
standard deviations.
In this case, if you take $k = 2981$ and
$$x^2 = \frac{k^2}{\sigma^2} = \frac{8886361}{25000},$$
then
$$ \frac{ 
\displaystyle{  \frac{1}{2^{100000}} \binom{100000}{52981}}
}
{
\displaystyle{
\frac{e^{-8886361/50000}}{100 \sqrt{5 \pi}} }
}
= 0.90153\ldots
$$
which shows that already for $N$ in this range the answer above is quite accurate, the first actual value strictly below 10% occurring at $52994$ which is only $13$ away. So if you are within 18 standard deviations then the approximation is valid to within 10% but not at 19 standard deviations, and in general the number of standard deviations is (as seen above) asymptotic to $N^{1/4} \cdot 1.06038\ldots$. More generally, if you are $o(N^{1/4})$ standard deviations away the relative error will be negligible, if you are $\Omega(N^{1/4})$ standard deviations the relative error will approach 100%, and if you are $N^{1/4} y$ standard deviations away the relative error is $\sim 1 - e^{-y^4/12}$.

Comment: Welcome @Pound Stirling! Could you give a reference or an explanation for your application of Stirling's Formula?

Comment: Also, shouldn't the limit be $1-y^4/12$ instead of $e^{-y^4/12}$?